# How to stop electric fluctuation while using PIR sensor

Tags: relay, triac, proximity-sensor, pir

I used a triac to control the AC current to my led bulb  but once the bulb is in on state, it's flickering.

I made a bridge rectifier and using transistor connected to triac, the input is given through PIR sensor

How can I reduce flickering, should I use a relay instead of triac. I just want to ON and Off based on pir sensor detects object

I read somewhere that it's because of small current.[image][image]

I did exactly same in this youtube video
https://youtu.be/6Bua0g8HDIY

Comment: I don't think flatuation is a proper word. Flatulation is but that means fart.

Comment: Do you want the light bulb to be just ON or OFF, or should the brightness also be controlled ? If brightness control is also required, I do not think a relay alone can do it. Please [edit] into your question a circuit diagram representing your circuit, and the part numbers / values of the components used in the circuit. Also add the specifications of the LED bulb. Does it accept DC or AC ? If so at what voltage.

Comment: I use 20 w led tube light and want to ON and off based on pir detect object

Comment: use a relay instead of that death-trap circuit.

Comment: Current is probably too low for the hold-current of your TRIAC.